# Route [voyager.database.bread.edit] not defined. Voyager Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-blade, voyager

Can someone tell me what is this about? It works fine on my local server(i use valet) and on a live website. But on staging server when I try to open a database in the voyager admin panel it "Whoopses" and throw me this route not defined error. Thank you

```
Route [voyager.database.bread.edit] not defined. (View: /home/forge/staging.origintrail.io/vendor/tcg/voyager/resources/views/tools/database/index.blade.php)


public function route($name, $parameters = [], $absolute = true)
{
    if (! is_null($route = $this->routes->getByName($name))) {
        return $this->toRoute($route, $parameters, $absolute);
    }

    throw new InvalidArgumentException("Route [{$name}] not defined.");
}
```